# A question about STM32 global timers

Tags: stm32

Regarding the following code for an STM32F407 board:

```
TIM7->ARR = 333;
TIM7->CNT = 0;
HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim7);
```

I have set the timer such that it counts after each 1us by:

[image]

and enabled its interrupt as:

[image]

I want to generate and interrupt when ARR regsiter becomes 333 which in turn makes CNT register zero.

When CNT is reloaded(set to zero) will an update event is generated regardless of ARR?

Will the first interrupt(update event) occur at the very beginning since I set it to zero by TIM7->CNT = 0 or will it occur after ARR becomes 333?

Answer (score -1):

Coincidencially, I've been reading STM32 timer documentation literally today to figure out what's going on there, so there are some useful resources:

1. Your datasheet (not very useful for timers, but take a look), MCU reference manual (all registers and general description of functions, still overwhelming and confusing)
2. AN4776 (detailed description of functionality, a lot of info, head hurts)
3. AN4013 (can't say much, only quickly glanced, but 2 seemed to cover more)

Start with 1 and 2, you can look at 3 later. Tbh, my mind is exploding from the amount of info. It will take some time for everything to sink in, but as far as I understand at this point:

On reset CNT is undefined, so in theory you shouldn't have to clear the update even flag, but I met some code snippets in document 2), which do that. Just one line of code not to think about it anymore:

```
TMR->SR &= ~TIM_SR_UIF;
```

Where TMR is your timer. This force-clears update event interrupt flag in the timer status register.

From the document 2, page 7-8:

[image]

[image]

Ignore the repetition part for your timer. It seems if you're downcounting, you will actually trigger an event. If upcounting, obviously, no.

This is from my STM32F746 reference manual, timers are same/similar between STM32 devices, downcounting and upcounting:

[image]

[image]

Also, ARR register doesn't *become* anything, it's usually fixed. It's a reload value to be loaded into CNT.

**EDIT**

I had near-ready test code at hand, so I modified it to test the hypothesis if interrupt triggers immediately if upcounter starts with CNT = 0.

bsctmr.c:

```
#include "bsctmr.h"

void basic_timer_setup(TIM_TypeDef *TMR) {
    TMR->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_ARPE | TIM_CR1_URS; //ARR is buffered | only overflow/underflow generates update event.
    TMR->PSC = (108000U / 2U) - 1U; //APB1 is 54MHz, timer is 2x APB1 Freq, so now the timer is at 2kHz; 16-bit value!!! 65535 max!
    TMR->ARR = 6000U; //6000 ticks at 2kHz is 3s
    TMR->CNT = 0U; //start value 0
    TMR->DIER |= TIM_DIER_UIE; //update event interrupt enable
    TMR->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_OPM; //one pulse mode

}

void basic_timer_start(TIM_TypeDef *TMR) {
    TMR->EGR = 0x01; //force update the registers from their buffer values if there is one
    TMR->SR &= ~TIM_SR_UIF; //make sure the update flag is cleared
    if (TMR == TIM6) {
        NVIC_SetPriority(TIM6_DAC_IRQn, 1U);
        NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM6_DAC_IRQn);
        NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(TIM6_DAC_IRQn); //clear interrupt pending flag in NVIC

    }
    if (TMR == TIM7) {
        NVIC_SetPriority(TIM7_IRQn, 1U);
        NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM7_IRQn);
        NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(TIM7_IRQn); //clear interrupt pending flag in NVIC
    }
    TMR->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN; //enable timer

}

void TIM6_DAC_IRQHandler(void) {
    TIM6->SR &= ~TIM_SR_UIF; //clear update event interrupt flag in timer peripheral
    NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(TIM6_DAC_IRQn); //clear interrupt pending flag in NVIC

    toggle_led1();
}
```

with main.c code doing nothing but:

```
#include "main.h"

int main(void) {
    rcc_setup(); //clock for peripheral, clock will be set to 216MHz
    gpio_setup(); //set pin modes and functions
    systick_setup(SYSTEM_FREQUENCY);
    basic_timer_setup(TIM6);
    basic_timer_start(TIM6);
    while (1) {
    }
}
```

Notice the first line of basic_timer_start. I didn't have it before and it always triggered immediate interrupt as soon as I activated the timer. Even if I cleared the flags. Regardless of CNT value.

Anyway: CNT=0 does NOT trigger immediate interrupt and behaves exactly like CNT=1. So the way to go is to set CNT=ARR from the start.

**EDIT2:**

I made it! It IS CNT=ARR, but what matters is at what moment I set the CNT.

Now, when I set CNT I do it right one line of code before the timer is activated, and it behaves as expected. If I set CNT to 0, it takes some time to trigger an interrupt, because there is no overflow. If I make CNT=ARR as start value, it triggers immediately.

```
void basic_timer_setup(TIM_TypeDef *TMR) {
    TMR->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_ARPE | TIM_CR1_URS; //ARR is buffered | only overflow/underflow generates update event.
    TMR->PSC = (108000U / 2U) - 1U; //APB1 is 54MHz, timer is 2x APB1 Freq, so now the timer is at 2kHz; 16-bit value!!! 65535 max!
    TMR->ARR = 6000U-1U; //2000 ticks at 2kHz is 6s
    //TMR->CNT = 4000U; //start value 0
    TMR->DIER |= TIM_DIER_UIE; //update event interrupt enable
    TMR->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_OPM; //one pulse mode

}

void basic_timer_start(TIM_TypeDef *TMR) {
    TMR->EGR = 0x01; //force update the registers from their buffer values if there is one
    TMR->SR &= ~TIM_SR_UIF; //make sure the update flag is cleared
    if (TMR == TIM6) {
        NVIC_SetPriority(TIM6_DAC_IRQn, 1U);
        NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(TIM6_DAC_IRQn); //clear interrupt pending flag in NVIC

        NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM6_DAC_IRQn);

    }
    if (TMR == TIM7) {
        NVIC_SetPriority(TIM7_IRQn, 1U);
        NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(TIM7_IRQn); //clear interrupt pending flag in NVIC

        NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM7_IRQn);
    }
    TMR->CNT = TMR->ARR; //start value ARR for immediate interrupt
    TMR->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN; //enable timer

}
```

Notice I set CNT literally one line before I actually enable timer. It solved all the problems for me.

Comment: HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim7); will start TIM7. And the moment TIM7 starts CNT is zero. Does that mean initially(when TIM7 starts) there will be update event? That is my question.

Comment: The answer is in the bottom graphs. If you're downcounting, there will be event on CNT=0 to CNT=ARR transition, if upcounting, no.

Comment: Strange because I get that update event initially.

Comment: Timer 7 is a basic timer, I think, so it's only downcounting. Then, as it obviously follows from the figure 216 I provided, yes. There will be an update event on CNT=0 to CNT=ARR. Why not load CNT with ARR and not with 0? This timer goes down, not up

Comment: Oh wait a second. I set it here as UP https://i.stack.imgur.com/yN2fm.png Isnt that mean up counting (TIM7)?

Comment: Oh so its down counting.. And the initial update event something not I avoid that's what I also want. I asked the question out of curiosity

Comment: Let me check documentation. Maybe it's a generic interface for all timers and for this one it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Yes, they are UP only. I was wrong. It may be triggered by 0 value in CNT then. Try starting with CNT value of 1.

Comment: I "want" a trigger at the beginning. Not the other way around. So I guess Im fine with that

Comment: Then you can set CNT to ARR as initial value to guarantee it.

Comment: Thanks for thorough answer

Comment: @ty_1917 what stops you from actually testing it? it's not like you need to change much code for that (I mean cnt=0) when/if you do, let us know

Comment: I test it but since delay is only 333us I cannot figure out whether the first update trigger is at the very beginning or after 333us.

Comment: I have an idea to check it using an output pin. But will get back maybe tomorrow

Comment: @ty_1917 I actually have an example project with basic timer TIM6 identical to TIM7, I've modified it to test. Found an unaccounted bug in my code. I will edit in my test code now.

Comment: `On reset CNT is undefined` it is wrong. On reset timer clock is disabled and CNT (same as all other registers) will be read as zero (despite its value). When you enable the clock after the reset the value of CNT **is guaranteed** to be **zero**

Comment: `TMR->ARR = 6000U; //6000 ticks` no, it will be 6001 ticks. You do not have to add `U` as it ARM integers are 32bits long

Comment: oh yeah I accidentally deleted -1U while modifying; I like being explicit, peace of mind)

Comment: I set CNT=ARR still doesnt work for me. I need interrupt at the very beginning.

Comment: This is very strange. What about CNT=ARR-1? It counts up, so as per images, it should trigger on overflow. EDIT: I'm getting the same thing. Playing with my example now to figure it out

Comment: I fixed it! Let me edit in the changes I made

Comment: I made TIM7->ARR = CHANNEL_DELAY; and next line TIM7->CNT = CHANNEL_DELAY -1; and next line HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim7); It still waits CHANNEL_DELAY for the first trigger. It doesnt trigger/update at the beginning

Comment: @ty_1917 edit made. You may wanna do TIM7->EGR = 0x01 and make sure no flags are set at the wrong moments. Oh and I think I should actually swap nvic clear flag and interrupt enable lines, my error (fixed)

Comment: No luck. Do u mind if I share the entire code with you?

Comment: I'll move it to the chat then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134520/discussion-between-ilya-and-ty-1917).